# Как записать числа из текстового файла в переменные?

Tags: python, текстовые-файлы

Я только начал изучать пайтон, поэтому вопрос может быть слишком уж простым. Есть задача, в которой нужно для легендарного fizzbuzz брать числа из другого текстового файла. Изначально я написал программу, которая берет числа из input. Как теперь в нее подключить чтение чисел из другого файла? Если что, то это задание после изучения модуля sys

```
fizz = int(input())
print("Buzz:")
buzz = int(input())
print("3 number:")
num = int(input())
i = 1
while i <= num:
    if i % fizz == 0 and i % buzz == 0:
        print("FB")
    elif i % fizz == 0:
        print("F")
    elif i % buzz == 0:
        print("B")
    else:
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Ну вы же можете открыть файл, прочитать из него три строчки и положить их в переменные? Это просто и можно сделать разными способами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если после sys, то:

```
import sys

original_stdin = sys.stdin

filein = open("data.txt", 'r')
sys.stdin = filein

for x in range(0, 20):
    fizz = int(input())
    print("Buzz:")
    buzz = int(input())
    print("3 number:")
    num = int(input())
    i = 1
    while i <= num:
        if i % fizz == 0 and i % buzz == 0:
            print("FB")
        elif i % fizz == 0:
            print("F")
        elif i % buzz == 0:
            print("B")
        else:
            print(i)
        i+=1


filein.close()
sys.stdin = original_stdin
```

Данные из файла data.txt

Comment: А при чем тут тогда весь этот инпут? Мне нужно чтоб числа брались из другого текстового файла, в котором лежат 20 строк по 3 числа

Comment: Организуйте цикл перед переменной fizz и всё

Comment: Вы похоже не достаточно хорошо изучили SYS.

Comment: Спасибо большое, и правда нужно было больше самому почитать

Comment: Ну тогда ставте как ответ и закрываем вопрос:)

Answer (score 0):

```
file.read(size) # size - кол-во символов для считывания, 
# если size не указан, считывает весь файл
file.readline() # считывает из файла 1 строку
file.readlines() # считывает из файла все строки в список и возвращает его
```

Вариант 1:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\text.txt' # путь к файлу
f = open(file=path, mode='r') # mode='r' - открыть в режиме чтения
text = f.read()
f.close()
```

Вариант 2:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\text.txt' # путь к файлу
with open(file=path, mode='r') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Ничего в коде менять не надо!

Вносите числа в три строчкм в файл `123.txt`, а в консоли запускаете программу с чтением из текстового файла, т.е.

`python fb.py < 123.txt`

Если работате в PyCharm, там есть  в конфигурации запуска пункт `Redirect input from`

Comment: Менять надо, добавить цикл чтения 20-и значений по 3 штуки за раз. В вопросе указано, что прошли изучение модуля sys. Вероятно надо использовать эти знания в проекте